Next.js redirect to external URL but keeping the same domain
I have my project build in next.js 14.2 and hosted on heroku under my-app.com
Now I want to serve a external site as landingpage content my-landingpage.com without the user noticing that the domain changed (the domain in the brower shall still be my-app.com). As soon as the user navigates further, the content from my next.js project shall be reached (e.g. my-app.com/login). Is that possible?
I know how I can redirect the root directory to the external site but then in the brower it says my-landingpage.com but I want to keep my-app.com.
either in next.config.js
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        destination: 'https://my-landingpage.com'
      },
    ]
  },
};

or in middleware.js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export function middleware(request) {
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname === '/') {
    const externalLandingPageURL = 'https://test.de';
    return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL(externalLandingPageURL, request.url), 301);
  }
}


Hello. If my answer was good can you accept it please ? ^o^

sorry, sure thing! (:
